# Updating all created_at rows to be 10 minutes before in Ruby Sequel

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I am trying to take all the `created_at` timestamps in my table and decrement around 10 minutes from it (600 seconds). But I can't seem to figure it out.

```
MyApp::Model::MyTable.select(:created_at).update(:created_at => :created_at - 600)
```

I select all the rows from the `created_at` column and perform an update on said row so that each row is now `created_at` - 600 seconds (10 minutes). However, when I try this, it says `incompatible data types in combination`.

Can someone give me a better solution to this?

Comment: Among other things, this would be an unsafe approach since there is no guarantee that `- 600` would be interpreted as being in seconds. Or rather, there isn't a guarantee simply from the way the example code. I assume the "incompatible data types" is because `created_at` is a datetime datatype, and you are trying to interact with it like it's an integer.

Comment: This looks useful: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/date_arithmetic_rb.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the database with a SQL command to avoid loading all records into memory first:

```
MyApp::Model::MyTable.update_sql(
  created_at: Sequel.lit('DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)')
)
```

See the documentation of [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Comment: It seems like I don't have `update_all` in my Sequel: `NoMethodError: undefined method update_all' for MyApp::Model::MyTable:Class
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1657:in method_missing'`

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that you use `Sequel`. Please see my updated answer.